# MBRP ( model based recursive partitioning) with R "glmertree" got error "subscript out of bounds, not all 'rhs' available"

Tags: r

## Goal of analysis:

Orginally I ran multilevel regression on the data to exam how social network properties (SNPs) (e.g. degree, centralities, group size, group centralizations ...) affect individual's productivity outcome.
Now I would like to see if the relationship between the predictors (SNPs) and outcome (productivity) is similar or different in the subgroups, or discover the hidden subgroups in the data population.

## My main questions related to the error:

1. what does the error mean? I tried check related in google and with chatgpt, but either I found too little similar issue or I do not understand the technical terms explaining the math machanism behind glmertree. Any eaiser understable explanation would be appreciated.
2. is the error cause by some issues in my dataset? For example, very little factor variables? distribution of values in each variables?

Because I ran glmer using a sample dataset from below links and it works fine:
data file ( https://scholarlypublications.universiteitleiden.nl/handle/1887/3210476 ,
codes: https://scholarlypublications.universiteitleiden.nl/access/item%3A3210478/view)

3. what is the basic requirement of glmertree? what kind of data it is suitable?
4. is there other better packages to achieve my goal of analysis? or other method rather than MBRP?

## Error I got :

```
Warning message in formula.Formula(ff, lhs = 1L, rhs = c(1L, 3L)):
“subscript out of bounds, not all 'rhs' available”
Error in attr(ff, "rhs")[[2L]]: subscript out of bounds
```

## What I did and results:

data2 = Full dataset for analysis, its summary is:

```
'data.frame':   14181 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ prodgap_relat_node_avg: num  2.56 2.56 2.56 2.56 2.56 ...
 $ clust                 : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ deg                   : num  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ const                 : num  0.375 0.375 0.375 0.375 0.375 ...
 $ nd_bet_cen            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ nd_cl_cen             : num  0.485 0.485 0.485 0.485 0.485 ...
 $ nd_ei_cen             : num  0.0666 0.0666 0.0666 0.0666 0.0666 ...
 $ fileteamsize          : int  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ teamlevel             : Factor w/ 5 levels "crowd","dyadic",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
```

```
prodgap_relat_node_avg     clust             deg            const        
 Min.   :0.000126       Min.   :0.0000   Min.   : 1.00   Min.   :0.06806  
 1st Qu.:0.639601       1st Qu.:0.1028   1st Qu.:12.00   1st Qu.:0.06806  
 Median :1.109216       Median :0.1846   Median :40.00   Median :0.10130  
 Mean   :0.852597       Mean   :0.3802   Mean   :36.27   Mean   :0.15289  
 3rd Qu.:1.114702       3rd Qu.:0.6818   3rd Qu.:60.00   3rd Qu.:0.23183  
 Max.   :4.062727       Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :60.00   Max.   :1.00000  
   nd_bet_cen        nd_cl_cen         nd_ei_cen       fileteamsize 
 Min.   :0.00000   Min.   :0.01515   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :1.00  
 1st Qu.:0.00239   1st Qu.:0.53043   1st Qu.:0.1500   1st Qu.:2.00  
 Median :0.17501   Median :0.70523   Median :0.3510   Median :3.00  
 Mean   :0.26680   Mean   :0.72023   Mean   :0.2935   Mean   :3.41  
 3rd Qu.:0.54622   3rd Qu.:0.91266   3rd Qu.:0.4298   3rd Qu.:4.00  
 Max.   :0.54622   Max.   :0.91266   Max.   :0.4298   Max.   :9.00  
       teamlevel   
 crowd      :2733  
 dyadic     :3416  
 group      :2518  
 solo worker:3288  
 tradic     :2226
```

To simplified, I created a subdata containing 50 observations of data2, summary of data3:

```
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ prodgap_relat_node_avg: num  2.56 2.56 2.56 2.56 2.56 ...
 $ clust                 : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ deg                   : num  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ const                 : num  0.375 0.375 0.375 0.375 0.375 ...
 $ nd_bet_cen            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ nd_cl_cen             : num  0.485 0.485 0.485 0.485 0.485 ...
 $ nd_ei_cen             : num  0.0666 0.0666 0.0666 0.0666 0.0666 ...
 $ fileteamsize          : int  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ teamlevel             : Factor w/ 5 levels "crowd","dyadic",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
```

```
prodgap_relat_node_avg     clust             deg            const        
 Min.   :0.0184         Min.   :0.1028   Min.   : 3.00   Min.   :0.06806  
 1st Qu.:0.4963         1st Qu.:0.1028   1st Qu.: 3.00   1st Qu.:0.06806  
 Median :1.1147         Median :0.2237   Median :31.00   Median :0.13111  
 Mean   :1.3344         Mean   :0.4362   Mean   :31.04   Mean   :0.19036  
 3rd Qu.:2.5566         3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:60.00   3rd Qu.:0.37485  
 Max.   :2.5566         Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :60.00   Max.   :0.37485  
   nd_bet_cen        nd_cl_cen        nd_ei_cen        fileteamsize
 Min.   :0.00000   Min.   :0.4848   Min.   :0.06663   Min.   :4    
 1st Qu.:0.00000   1st Qu.:0.4848   1st Qu.:0.06663   1st Qu.:4    
 Median :0.08885   Median :0.6398   Median :0.27468   Median :4    
 Mean   :0.20450   Mean   :0.6758   Mean   :0.25596   Mean   :4    
 3rd Qu.:0.54622   3rd Qu.:0.9127   3rd Qu.:0.42977   3rd Qu.:4    
 Max.   :0.54622   Max.   :0.9127   Max.   :0.42977   Max.   :4    
       teamlevel 
 crowd      : 0  
 dyadic     : 0  
 group      :50  
 solo worker: 0  
 tradic     : 0
```

My R code:

```
install.packages("glmertree")
library("glmertree")
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
getwd()
data <- read.csv("/content/github.android_final.csv")

data1 <-  data[, c("prodgap_relat.byfile.email._mean.bynode.","clust","deg","const","nd_bet_cen","nd_cl_cen","nd_ei_cen","fileteamsize")]
names(data1) <-c("prodgap_relat_node_avg","clust","deg","const","nd_bet_cen","nd_cl_cen","nd_ei_cen","fileteamsize")

data2 <- data1 %>%
  mutate(teamlevel = case_when(
    fileteamsize == 1 ~ "solo worker",
    fileteamsize == 2 ~ "dyadic",
    fileteamsize == 3 ~ "tradic",
    fileteamsize %in% c(4, 5) ~ "group",
    fileteamsize >= 6 ~ "crowd"
  ))
data2$teamlevel <- as.factor(data2$teamlevel)

data3 <- head(data2,50)

tree1 <- lmertree(prodgap_relat_node_avg ~ clust + deg + const + nd_bet_cen + nd_cl_cen + nd_ei_cen + teamlevel , data = data3)
tree2 <- lmertree(prodgap_relat_node_avg ~ clust + deg + const , data = data3)
tree3 <- lmertree(prodgap_relat_node_avg ~ clust , data = data3)
```

Error I got no matter tree1,2,or 3:

```
Warning message in formula.Formula(ff, lhs = 1L, rhs = c(1L, 3L)):
“subscript out of bounds, not all 'rhs' available”
Error in attr(ff, "rhs")[[2L]]: subscript out of bounds
```

**Note: I tried the glmertree formula on data2 as well, same error as data3.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a copy of my answer from https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/623264/173546, where the same question was asked:

Your model formulas are not glmertree formulas, hence the error. As per e.g. the tutorial you refer to, a glmertree formula comprises three parts, separated by vertical bars (`|`):

response ~ node-specific predictors | global predictors | partitioning variables

Your formulas appear to specify only the first part: response ~ node-specific predictors. This might not be what you intend.

You wrote about your prediction question:

> exam how social network properties (SNPs) (e.g. degree, centralities, group size, group centralizations ...) affect individual's productivity outcome. Now I would like to see if the relationship between the predictors (SNPs) and outcome (productivity) is similar or different in the subgroups, or discover the hidden subgroups in the data population.

Your code has:

```
tree1 <- lmertree(prodgap_relat_node_avg ~ clust + deg + const + nd_bet_cen + nd_cl_cen + nd_ei_cen + teamlevel , data = data3)
tree2 <- lmertree(prodgap_relat_node_avg ~ clust + deg + const , data = data3)
tree3 <- lmertree(prodgap_relat_node_avg ~ clust , data = data3)
```

These yield errors, because the global model part and partitioning variables seem to be missing or incorrectly specified.

It looks like `prodgap_relat_node_avg` is the response variable (an individual's productivity outcome), `clust` is an indicator for cluster, and `deg + const + nd_bet_cen + nd_cl_cen + nd_ei_cen + teamlevel` are a set of social network properties. Going by the description of your research question, you want to find subgroups for which the association between SNPs and the response is different. However, seven possible predictors is a bit much, glmertree is mostly useful if there is an effect of one specific predictor, maybe two, that is of interest (i.e., where you want to identify subgroups that differ in the effect of this predictor). Also, sometimes researchers are interested in finding intercept differences only, so they might only be interested in finding subgroups with different means. I am not completely sure what is the specific research question you want to address here.

There are many ways to turn the formulas you wrote into something that works with glmertree, but each will answer a different research question. I provide suggestions here, perhaps you can update your post with a more exact description of e.g. which are the predictor variables of interest, and which variables are possible subgroup descriptors (i.e., partitioning variables).

The following formula would fit a model that finds subgroups (described by variables `deg`, `const`, `nd_bet_cen`, `nd_cl_cen`, `nd_ei_cen` and/or `teamlevel`) with a different mean of `prodgap_relat_node_avg`, while accounting for correlations between observations with the same value of `clust`:

```
prodgap_relat_node_avg ~ 1 | clust | deg + const + nd_bet_cen + nd_cl_cen + nd_ei_cen + teamlevel
```

The following formula would fit a model that finds subgroups (described by variables `const`, `nd_bet_cen`, `nd_cl_cen`, `nd_ei_cen` and/or `teamlevel`) with a different intercept or slope of the regression of `prodgap_relat_node_avg` on `deg`, while accounting for correlations between observations with the same value of `clust`:

```
prodgap_relat_node_avg ~ deg | clust | const + nd_bet_cen + nd_cl_cen + nd_ei_cen + teamlevel
```

I am assuming `clust` is an identifier for the cluster that observations are part of, with respect to which a random intercept should be estimated.